# Android keyboard custom keys

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm developing a custom Android keyboard (I'm old in C# but very new in Java/Android). I started to develop my keyboard, based on [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) tutorial. It works very well but my problem that I would like to use my own custom image, skin or colour on the `Keys` instead of the default Android `Keys`.

I found many solution in this topic but I could not import any solution to my project, so I hope this post will be not mark as duplicate.

So my request is, if you can check the linked tutorial and give me some sample code please please do it.

Thank You!

Comment: Open the library and override the images in the Rec folder.

Comment: I do not fully understand. Could you give me some more information?

Comment: `res/layout/keyboard.xml` open this XML file and add `android:background` attribute to it.. **This is for keyboard Background**... Now open `res/xml/qwerty.xml` and try adding background to **<Keyboard  >**  just like before. Hope it helps.

Comment: I did it but nothing happend. :(

Comment: Post the updated code. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: **keyboard.xml**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview"
    android:background="@color/green"
/>`

**qwerty.xml**

`<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ...
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:background="@color/green">`

Comment: What exactly happens when you do this?

Comment: Now I added an extra Keyboard `Row` with only one `Key` so now the empty places are green, but the colour or skin of the `Keys` I can't change. For example instad of `Label` "**a**" I would like to use an image on this `Key`.

`android:background`, `android:keyIcon`, `android:keyTextColor`, `android:keyBackground` are not work in the `Keys` tag